# Who were the market for those "speed up your computer" shareware applications back in the day?

Tags: hardware, ibm-pc, software, performance, price

In the Swedish computer magazine *PC Hemma* ("Home PC") from February 1997 (p. 68), they included a floppy disk with shareware programs related to "trimming your PC", as well as a guide on how to use them in the magazine itself. These cost between $10 and $29 each to register (most of them the latter), and would stop working 30 minutes after you turned on the machine, or entirely after X days, as usual with "shareware".

But in the same magazine, in fact on the previous page, there is a "hardware price guide" where you can read that you, for example, could get a brand new 8 MB of RAM for that price, or a second-hand 16 MB! This was an era when most PCs had 8 MB RAM total, or 16 MB if lucky/rich.

So who in their right mind would pay for a little software utility to *possibly* save some microscopic resources when they could just buy physical hardware to *definitely* speed up/enhance their computer? I could understand if they were 100% freeware utilities, so "what's there to lose?", but again, they were "shareware", meaning payware. Plus you had to send money in a foreign currency (in this case) across the world and then wait for them to send back the floppies with the full utility... The postage alone probably cost a fortune on top of the price.

What exactly was the target audience for these commercial "PC trimmer" utilities?

The programs were called:

- "System Analyst" (freeware)
- "System Checker" (shareware - £10 GBP)
- "SpeedRAM" (shareware - $29.20 USD)
- "CD-Quick Cache" (shareware - $29 USD)
- "VramDir" (shareware - $10 USD)
- "Memory Status" (freeware)

Comment: Can you provide a reference to an article or advertisement for an example of this class of product?

Comment: How "much" was the "exchange rate" from "Swedish kronor" at the "time", "anyway"?

Comment: The credulous ?

Comment: Which magazine?  Is the issue viewable online?

Comment: I have updated the question with a list of the names and prices/licenses for the programs included in the floppy/guide.

Comment: @AlexHajnal "PC Hemma" 2 1997, page 68. I could not find any way to view it online, but I don't see the point since it's not in English?

Comment: I googled 'speedram' and they were apparently [still hawking it](https://www.winsite.com/Utilities/System-Tools/SpeedRAM/) up to 2009.   The accompanying explanation of its benefits is barely literate.  What it's doing, however, is just purging all working sets.

Comment: By all logic the market must have been the readers of that magazine - otherwise they wouldn't have advertised in it, or would they?

Comment: Snake-oil like this is still being sold today, any reason to believe there is anything particular about the target audience in 1997 vs the target audience in 2022? IOW, is this actually "retro"-computing or just "computing"?

Comment: This type of programs still exist today. I suppose the (expected) customers are those that don't update their computers every 2-3 year due to different reasons.

Answer (score 5):

Memory is a bit fuzzy, but in 1997, I really believe running Windows 95 with 8MB of RAM would have been quite painful.  32MB-48MB was likely the norm, so yeah, 8MB would have been somewhat cheap.

Also just off the top of my head I would bet that 8MB module is a SIMM for a 486-class or early Pentium PC and not an SD-RAM DIMM for a 1997 era computer.  (Things were moving very quickly in the 90's.)  Probably a really old part.  I could be wrong.

A 16MB or 32MB module for a PC of that era was probably at least $100 - RAM was not known to be dirt cheap in those days unless really old.

A link to the article you are talking about would be interesting.

The latter half of the 90's was when the Internet first entered the public's consciousness.  A news story about "you can do X on the Internet" popped up almost every day it seemed.  At this time there was more or less the big rush of everyone--even non tech-savvy people--getting the latest desktop PC from a department store so they could use AOL over their dial-up connection.

It was the dawn of a new era and with the inrush of people new to computers, the market was pretty big for snakeoil and shovelware and other scams.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. In every other article, they mentioned how 16 MB was now somewhat of a standard for new computers, etc. Requirements for various new games/CD-ROM products often talked about 8 MB, etc. Your mentioned 32 MB-48 MB would be some kind of expensive server or heavy workstation. I would've scanned the article if it were in English, but it's not.

Comment: @Tarlton We're no strangers to non-English articles here. :-) Once upon a time, computers weren't US-centric.

Comment: @Tarlton If the _requirement_ was 8 MB, you really needed a lot more for everyday computing. That hasn't changed. _"Required"_ is of course the absolute bare minimum that the manufacturer got it working at, because they want it as low as possible to reach a larger market.

Comment: @Tarlton If it isn't too much trouble could you add images of those two pages (article and advertisement) to your question?

Comment: “Really believe” and “would have been” are **not** the basis for a good answer.  I recall 8-16MB being common RAM sizes in 1997.